# Angular translate strings from same source

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, translation, angular-translate

I am using [angular-translate](https://angular-translate.github.io) in my project.
I have multiple strings in my views which Id like to translate, like

```
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat ="title.value as title in vm.states">
</ul>
```

vm.states is an array which contains my project's all (except abstract) states.
There are some states looks like

`'user.details'` 
(not abstract state)

and

`'user.details.edit'`
And Id like to translate these strings, I have object in translation file

```
user: {
   details: {
      edit: "Edit User"
   },
   ...
}
```

Instead of dots Id like to write some text, which will be `user.details` translation, 
but I cant because json doesn't accept two properties with the same name.
Is it possible to translate these texts with angular-translate and keep states' names?

Comment: is not so clear what the problem but maybe if i understand well try 
var item = user.details.edit? user.details.edit : user.details;

Comment: @Erez Id like to translate 2 strings like `user.details` and `user.details.edit`, how to store them in translation .json file?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to associate your `angular-translate` references with state names. Infact for reusable translations it is best not too.

What you cannot do is have a record for both `user.details` and `user.details.edit`.

The reason for this is the `user.details` cannot be both a string and an object containing properties at the same time.

One way to solve this is to use UPPER_CASE for your translation containing objects and lower-case (or camelCase) for the property names.

You can have `USER.details` and `USER.DETAILS.edit`. Those do not conflict with each other.

Or you could do the inverse and have `user.DETAILS` and `user.details.EDIT`.

Comment: Thanks for reply Martin, I am working on existing project and its really hard to make changes on states, It would be fine if I can write something like `"user": { details: {"translation": "Details", edit : "Edit"} }`